# DDE Client in Service talking to a server in user session

Tags: c++, session, winapi, service, dde

I have written a C++ DDE client (console) app that talks to a third party dde server. This works fine when my client and server are in the same session. 
I then moved my client code into a win32 service running as SYSTEM. The client code is unable to get a server list in spite of trying the following:
1. I tried to enable "Allow service to interact with desktop" on Win7.
2. I have impersonated the user in the thread that tries to talk to the server.
3 I have tried to execute the client code as system.

I can understand the primary issue being comms across multiple sessions. But is there any way of achieving elegantly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with Vista, "interactive" services do not work anymore, because of **Session 0 Isolation**.

DDE is a User32-based technology (it uses window messages internally), and as such cannot be used across session boundaries.

To do what you are attempting, you will have to create a separate non-service app that runs in the context of a user session and uses DDE as needed, communicating back and forth with the service via a session-agnostic IPC mechanism, such as a named pipe, socket, or COM object.  The service can use `WTSQueryUserToken()` and `CreateProcessAsUser()` to run the app within a specific user session when needed.  Or you can configure the app to auto-run when a user logs in.

Comment: This is precisely what I decided to do. But I was just trying to find out if there is something that I've missed that can help me without spawning a separate process in the user context.

Comment: There is no other alternative if you need to use DDE.